# How to know PCIe switch type/model on the motherboard?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pci

I have a X570 UD motherboard. When running `lspci -ttvv` it seems like that there is a switch that connect the PCIe slots on the motherboard. How can I know the type/number of this PCIe switch ?

```
-01.2-[01-08]----00.0-[02-08]--+-01.0-[03]--+-00.0  GPU                                       
           |                               +-02.0-[04]---- NVMe
           |                               +-04.0-[05]----00.0  Device0
           |                               +-08.0-[06]--+-00.0  func0
           |                               |            +-00.1  func0
           |                               |            \-00.3  func3
           |                               +-09.0-[07]----00.0  Device1
           |                               \-0a.0-[08]----00.0  Device2
           |
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `lspci -v` should tell you about the PCI/PCIe devices. Can you provide that listing?

Comment: This "switch" is either your southbridge or directly your CPU.